# Use external JavaScript file's in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I'm trying to use external JavaScript files in angular 7 project and for this I have added multiple JavaScript files to angular.json file as in image

[JavaScript files added in angular.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn9yQ.png)

and also loading default multiple JavaScript files on page with make any reference manual so, from where they are refereed.

Please suggest the right way to use external JavaScript files in Angular 7 and also suggest how should we use the packages JavaScript files in Angular 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with what you've done?

Comment: Please don't use a link to an image. Some people cannot have access. Add the code directly to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using npm or is this just some file laying around? Using `import ...` should do the trick so long as it's a proper module

Comment: Why are you importing jQuery into Angular? Gross.

Comment: JavaScript files which I'm trying to use they are not loading on browser and also not showing as added (There are not any HTML tag **Script** which are showing my added JavaScript files).

Comment: _Why are you importing jQuery into Angular? Gross. – mwilson_  

This is what I want to ask when I have not added any reference of Jquery then from where it's referencing the Jquery and other files.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
....
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>`
Where is mentioned these files in Angular 7

Comment: See my answer below. I have also provided you an example using stackblitz.

Comment: ***Where is mentioned these files in Angular 7*** - please do some research on `@angular/cli`, what happens when you do `ng serve` or `ng build`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To import jQuery into an Angular app, you need to install it properly. **Opinionated** answer below.

1. `npm install jquery --save`
2. `import $ from 'jquery';`
3. Use jQuery
4. Think long and hard about why you are using jQuery still

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kcpz2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Why are you still using jquery? </h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: string;
  consturctor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    alert($('h1').text())
  }
}
```

You do not need to add it to your `angular.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer @mwilson but I want to know that as I mentioned previously that on browser there are some JavaScript files were loaded without any referenced, Where is this configured these files and as your answered, 

`import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';`

Jquery is loaded using this but where is mentioned these files.

Sorry If I'm asking something working  

I'm new in Angular

Comment: That's a hard question to answer if not impossible. Angulars Webpack bundling process will pull in anything being referenced. So, let' say you want to use bootstrap (like you're doing) and you go to install bootstrap with `npm install bootstrap`. Well. bootstrap requires jquery and a couple other modules so those will be installed too. You may not have explicitly installed, jQuery, but you're using a package that requires it.

Comment: There are some tools out there that might help you sniff out what is requiring jQuery, but from the screen shot, bootstrap is probably the culprit. The only places you can load scripts in an angular app are either through a direct script tag in the index.html, adding scirpts to the angular.json file, importing through npm and any other direct references in your webpack process.

Comment: Now I simply adding only three files in angular.json file which are not have any dependency of other files  

`
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [              
              "src/assets/scripts/fastclick/fastclick.min.js",
              "src/assets/scripts/adminlte/adminlte.min.js",
              "src/assets/scripts/adminlte/demo.js"
            ]
`
but still they are not showing on browser in script tag (Not showing in browser).

Comment: That's because you're not importing them correctly. You need to learn more about how angular works. Angular is not something where you can just throw a script in and expect it to work. You need to use es6 import statements and use npm to work with 3rd part libraries. If you have a custom script you're trying to use and it's way out of date, just throw it in the index.html as a script tag and `declare` a global variable for it so TypeScript can properly ignore it.